# MacOS to use Option as Meta Key by default for all profiles

Tags: terminal, keyboard, macos

There's an option in Terminal.app -> Preferences -> Settings -> Keyboard but it only allows me to set *one profile at a time*.

Any easy way to toggle such option to all profiles pls?

[image]

Comment: It'd take longer to create and test some solution vs just checking them.  It probably took longer to write the post and add the screenshot.

Comment: Let me ask it this way then, all linux-based tools use text file for their configurations -- all those clicking on the GUI side will translate into text changes in their configuration files. I.e., if I know what to change in the text configuration files, I don't need to redo all those clickings ever again. I don't know how it'd play out in the mac world. CC: @MarcWilson